# MVC5 How can I retrieve all users from Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory

Hi I'm relatively new to Azure. I want to create a dropdownlist that contains all the user's display name from the Azure's Active Directory but I'm not sure how to do it.

I briefly looked at the graph API from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations but I don't know how to call it in MVC nor getting the JSON data that contains the display name.

Any help or code example will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could get started using this Azure AD sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web, look at the [`WebAppGraphAPI/Controllers/UsersController.cs`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/blob/master/WebAppGraphAPI/Controllers/UsersController.cs) class, it does pretty much what you are looking for.

The code from the sample uses the SDK (found in the NuGet package `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`) and you get an object model for the graph results, not a JSON string. If you absolutely want to use the REST API then you could (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsers) but the SDK should be much more convenient for you since you can easily add the NuGet.

*Side note, you will need to register your application with the Azure AD in the portal and you need admin rights to do that.*

Comment: i tried to clone that repo, but the build failed, is there any alternative resource?

Comment: This articles describes the sample and how to do it from scratch: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/. You should be able to follow that guide and then just copy the implementation code from the repo into your own project.