# Get all users from Azure Portal

Tags: azure, api, azureportal

Is there an API existing, which gives me details about the users I have in Azure Portal including their profile details?: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/UsersManagementMenuBlade/AllUsers

This should be accessed via a script, so no user interaction at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's possible using [Azure AD Graph API to Get Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#get-users--).

Related references that covers Graph API, PowerShell, C# ways are listed below:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api-quickstart
3. [MVC5 How can I retrieve all users from Azure Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816258/mvc5-how-can-i-retrieve-all-users-from-azure-active-directory)
4. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog
5. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/336b0228-d8de-4423-8b65-bdfc2c5665c5/c-pulling-a-list-of-all-azure-active-directory-users-using-graph-api-stuckerrortimeout?forum=WindowsAzureAD
6. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0
7. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Extract-user-list-from-6cb9a93c
8. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/view-user-accounts-with-office-365-powershell